# Como implementar os method em Json usando Serializable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, restful

Estou fazendo um *webservice* onde quero retornar os dados em JSON, como eu poderia implementar os métodos, qual a melhor forma?

- GET
- PUT
- DELETE
- POST

Eu fiz um método GET, ficou assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

    [WebMethod]
    public string getUsuario(string id)
    {
        var json = "";
        var usuario = from result in dc.TB_USUARIOs
                      where result.controleusuario == Int32.Parse(id)
                      select result;
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        json =  jss.Serialize(usuario);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Os Webservices ASMX só suportam **POST** e **GET**. O ASMX é uma tecnologia legada e não devia ser considerada em [novos desenvolvimentos](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/), principalmente porque a Microsoft, desde 2009, anunciou não mais fazer melhorias nesta tecnologia.

Sugiro utilizar [Web.Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api), que é a tecnologia mais recente do .Net para criação de serviços REST e suportam todos os métodos HTTP que você precisa. Ou mesmo o [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - [neste artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254714/Implement-CRUD-operations-using-RESTful-WCF-Servic) há um bom exemplo de como usar os diferentes métodos HTTP com WCF.

Ainda assim, fica aqui uma dica se deseja usar POST com ASMX: basta adicionar o atributo [ScriptMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) com o parâmetro `UseHttpGet` com valor `false`, assim:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public string UmMetodo()
{
    return "Olá Mundo!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como já dito pelo Marcus Vinícius, para implementar os HttpVerbs o ideal é utilizar o Web API.

Só para documentação, abaixo eu coloquei alguns links explicando como fazer isso em WCF. Veja que é bem mais complexo faze-lo pois o WCF é muito mais que uma simples plataforma para implementação de Web Services ou REST Services.

- [A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)
- [A Beginner's Tutorial on Creating WCF REST Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)

Comment: Luiz, bem vindo ao SOPt. Links podem estar offline num futuro próximo (o que invalidaria sua resposta). Sugiro que [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/70450/edit) sua resposta e forneça conteúdo para os links.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme já visto pelas outras respostas, não é recomendado usar *WebServices*, mas isto não significa que não seja possível.

Decorei seu método `getUsuario` de forma com que ele devolva um JSON válido, utilizando `POST`:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public string getUsuario(string id)
{
    var json = "";
    var usuario = from result in dc.TB_USUARIOs
                  where result.controleusuario == Int32.Parse(id)
                  select result;

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    json = jss.Serialize(usuario);

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?